# Why "print" was a statement in Python until the "print()" function was introduced?

Tags: python, printing, programming-languages

Why "print" was (and still is, until the end of support of Python 2) a statement in Python? There should be some reason behind the choice of a statement over a function when Python was first created. Was there some benefit in doing so in those days, or was it just influence from some other languages? Which languages?

When searching this question, I found countless posts on why the print() function is better, but none explained why there was this statement in the first place.

Comment: I suspect the answer is simply "it was a mistake". It showed up on a presentation by Guido in 2002 titled [Python Regrets](http://legacy.python.org/doc/essays/ppt/regrets/PythonRegrets.pdf)

Comment: If it was influenced by another language, it would be interesting to know which language. It certainly wasn't C.

Comment: BTW, the `print` function _is_ available in Python 2.6+ via the `__future__` import.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks but it's not relevant to this question. This is not a question on Python 2/3 difference or compatibility.

Comment: @BryanOakley Python Regrets didn't say why it was like that, so I came and asked this question. Thank you for posting the URL though.

Comment: Understood, I just mentioned it for the benefit of other readers who may see this page, since many people do not realise that they can (and should) use the print function in Python 2. With any luck, one of the Python core devs will see this question and be able to share their historical knowledge.